# Why does using df[[column_name]] dislays a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I was just asking myself: I understand that calling df[column_name] displays a Series because a DataFrame is built of different arrays.
Though, why does calling df[[column_name]] (column_name being only one column) returns a DataFrame and not a Series ? I'm ont sure to understand the logic behing how Pandas was built here

Thanks :)

I was trying to explain to my students why calling a list of one element displays a dataframe and not a Series, but did not manage

Comment: Numpy arrays do something similar.  If `arr` is 2d, `arr[9]` is 1d, a  row.  `arr[[0]]` is 2d, with shape (1,n).

Answer (score 2):

If select columns of `DataFrame` by list, get DataFrame by subset of nested list (double [[]]).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col3', 'col2'], index=[0,5])
df1 = df[['col1','col2']]
print (df1)
  col1 col2
0  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
```

So if pass one element list, get single column `DataFrame`.

```
df2 = df[['col1']]
print (df2)
  col1
0  NaN
5  NaN
```

For Series is necessary only pass single column name inside a single set of square brackets, it obviously return Series.

```
s = df['col1']
print (s)
0    NaN
5    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

But if duplicated columns names instead `Series` get DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col1', 'col2'], index=[0,5])

df3 = df['col1']
print (df3)
  col1 col1
0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

It may happend because when you give single column_name as a string it takes it perform selection and return single value based on the search key column_name.
But when you provide same column_name contained in a list it tries to fetch all the keys of the list which in one in this case. Hence resulting a dataframe.

I guess they are using some standard logic to return dataframe if list is provided irrespective of length of list.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"],
data=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]])

column_name = "a"

print(type(df[column_name]))

print(type(df[[column_name]]))

output:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>